# "As" between "sth being considered" and an adjective

Tags: verbs, articles

It seems natural to me that something could be "considered as a [noun]" or "considered [adjective]", but trying to find some examples I found ones both confirming my assumptions as well as a few that seem to deny it:

> The following payments shall be considered as ‘very critical’ and the
>   [insert name of CB] shall use best efforts to process [...] them in
>   contingency situations

– from http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2007:237:0071:0107:EN:PDF

> [...] quotas for bananas pursuant to this Regulation should be
>   considered initially as non-critical within the meaning of Article
>   308c of Regulation (EEC) [...]

– from http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2004:282:0003:0005:EN:PDF

1. Is there some other rule in action here, e.g. putting the adjective in quotes requires the additional article?
2. Or is the article simply optional here?
3. Or are these examples wrong?
4. Finally, should there be an article in the following sentence:

> We have 21 comments, none of them considered as critical.

Comment: There is deletion involved: '... considered as being very critical' ---> '... considered as critical' ---> '... considered critical'.

Comment: Interesting, could you please elaborate a little bit or simply point me to a site at which I could read more on the correctness of these "transitional" forms of the sentence?

Comment: Look up 'deletion/s' and 'conversational deletion' in an on-site search. I should have dropped 'very' from the undeleted variant, as 'critical' suffices.